# How can I read what is already in a position on the console, based on coordinates? Assembly 8086

Tags: assembly, x86, x86-16

I am making a pacman game, and I need to check what is in the coordinates ahead of my character, so I can see whether or not it is possible for pacman to move into those coordinates. I have searched around quite a bit, but am unsure of how exactly to put this question into terms of a google search and have had little luck.

pseudo-code for what I want to do:

```
CheckNext PROC

go to coordinate position (champ_xnew,champ_ynew)

take what is in that position, store into next (next BYTE ?)
```

The part above (reading from memory) is what I need help with.

```
cmp next, '#' ;# is what I am using for walls

je NoMove

jne Move

Move:

champ_x = champ_xnew

champ_y = champ_ynew

NoMove:

return without changing champ_x/y

CheckNext ENDP
```

Comment: The screen is not a storage of information - it's an output device. While it's possible to read characters/pixels from the video memory, it's frowned upon. 

Store the structure of the level in memory. Then read (and write) it as you please.

Comment: @SevaAlekseyev If I remember correctly, at least in some VGA modes video memory can be used for saving sprites consisting of several bitplanes to be later copied to visible regions of video memory, a technique mentioned in Michael Abrash's Zen of Graphics Programming, 2nd Edition. Anyway, I agree with you that generally screen or video memory shouldn't be read by the program, only written, directly or indirectly.

Comment: That's not what the OP is after. The said technique is for graphics performance, not for (mis)using the video memory for state storage. It's very inefficient anyway, with bit planes and such.

Answer (score 2):

As long as the screen is in text mode (not in graphics mode) you may simply read back the screen data from the (segmented) address 0xB800:0x0000.

Answer (score 0):

Let's say you are using color text mode, so your screen begins at B800:0000 and you are using 8086 opcodes, i.e. not scaling in the efective address calculation. One row has then 160 bytes (each character cell fills two bytes: one for the character itself, and another one for the color).

```
mov al,[x]
mov bl,160
mul bl           ;AX = x*80*2
xor bx,bx
mov bl,[y]
add bx,bx        ;BX = y*2
add ax,bx        ;AX = x*160 + y*2
mov si,ax
mov ax,0b800h
mov es,ax        ;ES:SI points to the character at coordinates X,Y
mov al,es:[si]   ;AL has the ASCII code of character at coordinates X,Y
```

Answer (score 0):

To read a char and the color on a specific coordinate on the screen, there are two methods:

1. Use the function 08h of int 10h

input:

ah=08h
bh=number of screenpage (I always use 0)

output:

al=char
ah=color (the upper 4 bits and the lower 4 bits are foreground and backgroundcolor)

to find out the number of the screenpage, use function 0fh of int 10h

output:

al: current videomode
ah: number of cols per row
BH: NUMBER OF CURRENT SCREENPAGE

Function 0fh of int 10h will cause an error if it's used on the windows console, if the console

isn't in fullscreen mode.

2. Direct access to the video memory:

set the ds register to 0b800h, using "mov ax, 0b800h   mov es, ax"

set si to the offset of the char (NumberOfScreenpage*(cols*rows*2)+2*(row_number*cols+col))

load the WORD using lodsw

ah contains now the colors
al contains the char